# Issue with Compound Interest

Tags: exponential-function

Here is the question: 
Noha is investing ${$}2517$ in an account compounded monthly. She wants to have ${$}3000$ in $3$ years for a trip to Europe. What interest rate, to the nearest hundredth of a percent, compounded monthly, does she need?

I know that I need to use the formula $A=P(1+i)^{n}$

Here is how I substituted all my given values: $3000=2517[1+ (i/12)]^{36}$

I need assistance on how to find the interest rate, we never learned how to do that in class.

Comment: You can solve the equation by first dividing by 2517 (both sides) then taking the 36th root of both sides.  That'll leave you with # = 1 + i/12 which hopefully you can solve?

Answer (score 1):

You're on the right track.

$$\frac{3000}{2517} = (1 + \frac{i}{12})^{36}$$
$$ \sqrt[36]{\frac {3000}{2517}} = (1 + \frac{i}{12}) $$
$$1.0048 \approx 1 + \frac{i}{12}$$
$$0.0048 \approx \frac{i}{12}$$
$$0.0587 \approx i$$

Then, multiply by 100 to get the percentage value:

$$i \approx 5.87\%$$

Comment: It would be better to say multiply by $100\%$ so that your final answer is $i \approx 5.87\%$.

Comment: I tried putting a percent symbol but somehow it disappeared. Is there a Tex symbol for it?

Comment: In LaTeX, you have to type \% to obtain a $\%$ symbol.